# Constructing Puzzles

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-creation

How do you construct puzzles like Einstein's fish riddle, in which you need to know all the information about a set of objects to solve it, but you provide only the barest information that will let the user arrive at one unique solution.

Also can I get links to these type of puzzles. I absolutely love them.

Comment: This is something you might enjoy to read about *solving* these type of puzzles, having sufficient knowledge of mathematics: https://web.stanford.edu/~laurik/fsmbook/examples/Einstein'sPuzzle.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe its a somewhat identical process as to how say, a Sudoku puzzle is made - just using a Logic grid instead.

Start with an empty logic grid, and slowly populate your constraints until only one possible unique solution exists. Of course it is more involved than simply that, however that is a starting point as to how you may do it...